# libcurl4-openssl-dev : Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev but 1.0.2q-2 is to be installed

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, alexa-voice-service

So, Im trying to install Alexa in my raspberry Pi 3b+, but when I run 
`sudo bash setup.sh config.json` it just comes out with this error. I've tried installing many things, tried installing the version it shows in the error like
`sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev=1.0.2q-2` but it says that it doesnt exist. Then saw someone saying that I needed to enable precise-updates repository, but I dont know how to do that in Raspbian. Any help would be appreciated.

Also here is the whole message

```
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease     
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease  
Reading package lists... Done              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.6).
gcc is already the newest version (4:8.3.0-1+rpi2).
gcc set to manually installed.
git is already the newest version (1:2.20.1-2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.14.4-1).
libssl1.0-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2q-2).
libasound2-dev is already the newest version (1.1.8-1+rpt1).
python3-pip is already the newest version (18.1-5+rpt1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev but 1.0.2q-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `pi.sh` file and remove the `libssl1.0-dev` from the list of dependencies and save it.

Now try the install again using `sudo bash setup.sh config.json`